# Conveter of CSV file into JSON with child element

Tags: javascript, json, csv, converters

I got these CSV to be converted to JSON, I got million of them:

```
"pcid","category","synonym_category"
20019,"Accountant","accounting,tax"
20047,"Acoustical Consultant","acoustic, acoustics, noise, sound"
```

watch the **synonym_category** that I need to convert it into nested elements/array.

like the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "pcid":    2119,
    "category":"Accountant",
    "synonym_category":[
      {"1":"accounting"},
      {"2":"tax"}
     ]
  },
  {
    "pcid":    2047,
    "category":"Acoustical Consultant",
    "synonym_category":[
      {"1":"acoustic"}, 
      {"2":"acoustics"}, 
      {"3":"noise"}, 
      {"4":"sound"}
     ]
  }
]
```

I don't need PHP, Javascript or any programming solution, I need a converter (online or maybe a software that solve this situation. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Comment: @hofan41 It does convert CSV to JSON but it doesn't solve my situation

Comment: I think that's as close as you're gonna get to solving your situation without a programming solution. Good luck!